# How to set multiple properties without multiple try catch blocks and calls multiple services - Typescript?

Tags: typescript, service, properties, try-catch

I am gathering data to set for a list of properties, however it calls many different services to help obtain this data. If there is a problem with any of the services it would throw an error.
If an error is thrown I want the data to just return null for that specific property, and continue getting the rest of the data.

How do I do this without wrapping each service call in a try catch block?

I.E) this get all the properties, but if anything fails, the properties afterwards will not be set.

```
public async getAllProperties(){
try {
 const [studentYear, numOfCourses, numOfSemesters, startDate, gradDate] = 
await Promise.all([
   studentService.getStudentYear(), 
   courseService.getNumOfCourses(),
   semesterService.getNumOfSemesters(), 
   .... (etc)
])} catch (e){
   console.log("error with getting Properties");
 }
}
```

For example if I call getAllProperties() and the courseService throws an error, I want numOfCourses to be null, and for it to continue to check semesterService.getNumofCourse and continue setting the rest of the properties.

How can I do this without try catch for each service? I.E I don't want to write this for each property

```
try {
studentService.getStudentYear
} catch (e){
console.log("error in student Year");
studentYear = null;
}

try {
courseService.getNumOfCourses()
} catch (e){
console.log("error in get Num Of courses");
numOfCourses = null;
}
```

Thanks for any assistance or ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Alex's solution. But incase the resulting `{status: "fullfilled", value: 2018}` is a problem, here's my proposed solution:

```
var obj = {
  getStudentYear: () => new Promise(res => res(2018)),
  getNumOfCourses: () => new Promise(res => res(8)),
  getFailed: () => new Promise( (res, rej) => rej('failed'))
}

async function resolveOrNull(func){
  try{
    let x = await func()
    return x;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  }
}

async function getAllProperties() {
  return {
    studentYear: await resolveOrNull(obj.getStudentYear),
    numOfCourses: await resolveOrNull(obj.getNumOfCourses),
    getFailed: await resolveOrNull(obj.getFailed)
  }
}

getAllProperties()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Edit: So let's say you wanted to make a test to your code. You mock the functionality and now you want to make sure the resulting `studentYear` was equal to an expected value of `2018`:

If you're using a primitive value you can just do this:

```
 let studentYear = test.getStudentYear() // returns 2018
 studentYear === 2018 // this is TRUE
```

If you're using an object:

```
let studentYear = test.getStudentYear() // returns {status: "fullfilled", value: 2018}
studentYear === {status: "fullfilled", year: 2018} // this is FALSE
```

When Javascript compares one object to another object, it's compared by it's reference, not by it's values. I've run into plenty of other headache's when using objest/arrays and try my best to avoid it when possible. Which it often isn't, and honestly it's usually fine, but they do tend to over complicate things that could otherwise be very simple.

Edit2: (This is starting to get a bit "sloppy")

```
//... previous code
let globalVariable;

getAllProperties()
  .then((res) => {
    globalVariable = res;
    useGlobal();
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

function useGlobal() {
  console.log(globalVariable); // This contains the correct obj
  //  anything else that uses the global variable 
  //    should be called inside this function
}

console.log(globalVariable); // This is undefined
```

Edit3: (This is more along the lines of what you should be doing, but there's quite a few different ways to handle the problems that come with async code)

```
getAllProperties()
  .then(useAllProperties)
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

function useAllProperties = (res) => {
  console.log(res);
  // run code that needs the data
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where does the `{status: "fullfilled", value: 2018}` issue come from?

Comment: @Suzy I implemented Alex's answer and saw that the `Promise.allSettled` returns an object instead of a straight value. Sometimes objects can be a bit of a headache in javascript, but I'm not sure if that's going to be the case in your situation. (I'll throw in an example with an edit to explain how objects can cause a headache)

Comment: Great thanks Michael! Yes that's an important catch to note. An alternative to `Promise.allSettled`

Comment: Is there a way to get the res and err to print out in the same order, instead of it split up? I.E) const [testA, testBFails, testC]. It logs ["a", fail, "c"]. Instead of logging ["a", "c"] and [fail] in the catch response

Comment: Edit: Thanks, ignore the above comment I misunderstood. I tried setting the result in a global variable to be accessed elsewhere in the file. But it's showing undefined. Is it not possible to set "res" to a global variable in the then block?

Comment: @Suzy You "kind of" can, but really it's a problem with the "call stack", not so much "setting the variable". Basically your code on the global scope is running before the code inside the `.then` scope is running (because it's asynchronous). I think your best bet is to add a function that calls what you want to run inside the `.then` block, after the assignment. I added an edit to my post to show an example. If that doesn't work, I'd need to see more code to be more help.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the reply! Yes it works if I call another function inside. Would that be the same as using await on the promise, instead of Promise.then?

Comment: @Suzy Often, I prefer using await, but it does require you to write out a async function, then a try-catch block if you want error handling, so it's a little more work. But yes, using `const res = await Promise` inside of an `async function` would do the same thing as `.then(res => ...)`. Sorry if you got a buch of alerts because of the edits, new keyboard lol.

Comment: Okay I see, that makes sense. No worries, congrats on the new keyboard lol, and thanks so much for your explanations and help!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `Promise.allSettled`. This method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Each promise must use `try catch` to detect an error, and return `null` if there is an error. You can create a function which will await a Promise, and either return the result or null if there is an error. This way you only need to use `try catch` once.

Here is a code example of it in use. https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1nkhf4

```
function getAllProperties() {
  Promise.allSettled([getName(), getAge()]).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
}

function getName() {
  return returnNullIfFail(() => new Promise((res, rej) => res("some name")))
}
function getAge() {
  return returnNullIfFail(() => new Promise((res, rej) => rej("some error")))
}

async function returnNullIfFail<T>(somePromise: () => Promise<T>) : Promise<T | null> {
  try {
    return await somePromise()
  } catch (err) {
    return null
  }
}

getAllProperties()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and detailed answer!